# Derivative of Inverse Polynomial Function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Show that $f(x) = x^3 + 6x +8$ has an inverse and find the derivative of the inverse function.

- It's easy to show that $f$ is continuous and that it must have an inverse, but when it comes to taking the inverse of the function it gets extremely messy. Is there some shortcut that I'm missing that would make this problem a little bit more manageable?

Comment: You don't have to solve the cubic and then differentiate. You just differentiate $y=x^3+6x+8$ and then find $\frac{dx}{dy}$ rather than $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Think about why that works! So $dy=(3x^2+6)dx$, and hence $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{3x^2+6}$. Of course putting that in terms of $y$ gets messier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : The derivate $f'(x)=3x^2+6$ is positive for all $x\in \mathbb R$. Probably, you did this part already.

Suppose, $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$  is the inverse of $f(x)$. Then, we have $g'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(g(x))}=\frac{1}{3g(x)^2+6}$

Since we cannot write down $g(x)$ explicitely (the inverse function would be very complicated) , this will be the best we can do.